# iPhone is confused with iMessages

Tags: ios, iphone, messages

I have a contact, Niels; he has an iPhone too, and he uses iMessages, just as I am. For some reason, I've got 2 conversations going on with Niels although the contact card both contains the e-mail and the phone number.

[image] [image]

When you delete one conversation, you delete both conversations.

Am I using iMessages the wrong way?
Is this a known bug?
Is my iPhone messed up with the use of BiteSMS and other jailbreak tools?

Comment: It's possible that one of you is using the phone number to initiate a message, and the other is using an email address.  Starting from a blank slate, send a message, and have Niels reply, do you then have a single session, or 2?  If this is behaving oddly, try initiating the chat with both email and phone numbers, and see what happens.

Comment: I've experienced the same behaviour. One chat with the phone number, another with the mail address.

Comment: @stuffe That could make sense... My recent contacts show me both his e-mail and his number. But shouldn't the iPhone match and merge both conversations?

Comment: @timbooo, how did you solve this? Or did you just endure from this *bug* (?)

Comment: @Michiel I didn't solve this. Was just an FYI comment so you don't feel alone. Still hoping Apple will merge them in a future version ;)

Comment: @michiel - No, they remain separate, imagine you have an iPhone and an iPad, messages to the phone number only go to the phone, messages to the email go to both.  It's a case of know how to reply.  If it merged the 2, which would it choose to reply to?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. You can add this as an answer if you want. It seems like it solved my question.

Comment: @stuffe Yes you're absolutely right. Forgot about that. Since I'm using a Wifi-only iPad I shouldn't have missed that.

Comment: OK, I tried to combine these comments into a generic answer - hope it still makes sense :)

Comment: @stuffe, it kind of does :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that one of you is using the phone number to initiate a message, and the other is using an email address.  Starting from a blank slate, send a message, and have Niels reply, do you then have a single session, or 2?  If this is behaving oddly, try initiating the chat with both email and phone numbers, and see what happens.

Your recent contacts will likely show both messages from e-mail and phone number.  You might think that the iPhone should match and merge both conversations but in fact they remain separate for good reason.  Imagine you have an iPhone and an iPad, messages to the phone number only go to the phone, messages to the email go to both. It's a case of knowing how to reply. If it merged the 2, which would it choose to reply to?  It would have to choose the email address, as it's portable, the phone number isn't.  Any attempt to merge could leave one of your devices only getting half the replies, or the inability to reply if replying to an iPad from an iPhone that has decided to use the phone number as the primary contact choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But yesterday, I was chatting with Niels on my iPad and my girlfriend was chatting with Niels on my iPhone. And all the messages came in the same conversation... How can you explain that?

Comment: If you both used the email address, then all devices would pick up the messages.  Niels does not know what device the messages came from, just the source address.  If the first message came from the iPad, then the first reply would have gone to your email address, which is likely registered to receive at for both iPhone and iPad, meaning your iPhone would receive a copy of the reply also.  From that point, further replies from your iphone will maintain the use of the email address. You're having 1 conversation, at Niels end, it just happens that you are using 2 devices at your end. Make sense?

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you very much for this clarification!